# What's the use of buffers in gate driving?

Tags: buffer, gate-driving

I wa slooking into the [demonstration board for the STDRIVEG600](https://www.st.com/resource/en/data_brief/evstdriveg600dg.pdf) 600V high speed half-bridge gate driver and the circuit below is used to convert a PWM to 2 signals.

What i didnt understand is why they used 2 buffers? I know that buffers are used to increase drive capability and for robust receiving of off-board signals whcih is probably the case here but why the second one ?
The NOT is used to get the complement of the PWM signal..Also why this one is buffered!?

Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sections on both high- and low-sides generate dead time. One needs a NOT gate but the other doesn't need a BUFFER, in theory.

However, to make the dead times as close as possible (i.e. almost equal for both of high- and low-sides) the buffer brings extra propagation delay which is almost equal to bottom NOT gate's. Normally there should be fixed resistors instead of potentiometers. Unless they are matched, they basically reduce the precision and possibility of equal dead-time generation.

The second buffers are there to increase the drive capability by eliminating the effect of series resistors.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the upper and lower sections of this driver are designed to take care of switching the upper and lower transistors in an H-bridge arrangement, since the lower output is an inverted version of the upper one.

However, both sections have a deliberate delay introduced on their rising edges, by the resistor/diode/capacitor networks between their ICs, presumably for dead-time.

The inputs to these dead-time networks needs to be nice and square, and since they require sources able to discharge C3 and C7 *very* quickly, they must also be very strong (low impedance), hence the two ICs on the left.

Even though those left-hand ICs provide a good low-impedance signal to drive the following dead-time delay networks, the outputs of the dead-time networks themselves are relatively high impedance (due to their resistances), inappropriate to drive the gate of an H-bridge member transistor.

Therefore another buffer IC is provided on each path, to provide the necessary gate current for the bridge transistors themselves.

It's also interesting to note that there are two buffers (or inverters) on each path, helping to keep the propagation delay balanced along those paths. Only the delay provided by the dead-time sections themselves actually contribute to dead-time.

Another interesting point is the use of schmitt trigger buffers for the final stages, driving the bridge gates. Positive feedback within these devices really boosts output slew rate, and also provides input hysteresis to avoid "half-way" output states and multiple output transitions (noise immunity). Also, they have a very well defined input transition threshold, useful for situations like this, where a capacitor (C3 or C7 here) is used to lower input slew rate, to introduce a delay.

The slew rate-limiting of C3 and C7 are a problem for the gates of the bridge transistors; they can cause the transistors to spend too much time in a not-quite-off, not-quite-on state, where they dissipate a lot of power. Use of schmitt triggers to drive those gates goes a long way to eliminating this "half-way" state.

Comment: The signals HIN and LIN will not drive the switching devices directly but will be the inputs to the STDRIVEG600 gate driver.